# How to add branding name and logo in android api level 12 and below api level using new android 12 behaviour changes in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-splash-screen

**I want to migrate existing splash screen with new Splash Screen api.Currently we are using android:windowBackground to display splashscreen**.Attached sample image for example.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i9zu.jpg

** Also check react-native-bootsplash library as this library give support for android 12 but how to add text below icon using this library?**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [windowSplashScreenBrandingImage](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#implement)

```
<item name="android:windowSplashScreenBrandingImage">@drawable/...</item>
```